# Rust: Why is lazy_static not working with some types

Tags: multithreading, rust, global-variables, mutex, lazy-static

I need to create some global mutable variables, using lazy_static! with some types works, but with some other types it doesn't. The mutex is to change value.

This works:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref foo: Mutex<String>: Mutex::new("".to_string());
}
```

This doesn't (the `Function` is js_sys::Function)

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref bar: Mutex<Option<Function>> = Mutex::new(None);
}
```

The error is: `*mut u8 is not safe to send between threads`

My current work-around is using thread_local! for global mutable vars, but I need threads. How to use `lazy_static` with all types?

Comment: The issue is hidden in the error message, `Function` has an internal `*mut u8` pointer and raw pointers are neither `Send` nor `Sync`. `Send` is a requirement of `lazy_static`, thus you get the error message. If it's safe to ensure unique access through `Arc<Mutex<Function>>` you could implement a thin wrapper and manually implement `Send` + `Sync` for it.

Comment: you can use `Pin<T>`